# Adding new feature to discourse

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, discourse

I am trying to add an WatchList feature in the existing code discourse ember rails application

I have addded the following code

```
 Discourse.Route.buildRoutes(function() {
    var router = this;

    this.resource('watchLists', { path: '/watch_lists' }, function() {
        this.resource('watchList', {path: ':watch_list_id'});
     });
  });
```

In the ember  Controller

```
 Discourse.WatchListsController = Discourse.ObjectController.extend({});
```

In the ember model

```
   Discourse.WatchList = Discourse.Model.extend({});

   Discourse.WatchList.reopenClass({
      find: function() {
          jQuery.getJSON("watch_lists").then(function(json) {
          var watch_lists = json.watch_lists.map(function(attrs) {
          return Discourse.WatchList.create(attrs);
      });
   });
```

In the ember view js

```
   Discourse.WatchListsView = Ember.View.extend({});
```

In  ember route js

```
     Discourse.WatchListsRoute = Discourse.Route.extend({
         model: function() {
            return Discourse.WatchList.find();   
         }
    });
```

When i renderring the handlebars template I am getting an WatchListsController object withot the data we have got from the ajax.

Can any body point out where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible problems.

First, you probably want `WatchListsController` to extend `Discourse.ArrayController`, not `Discourse.ObjectController`.

Second your `reopen` block is not valid JavaScript in the example code that you posted.  I count four `{` but only two `}`.  You probably want something kind of like this:

```
Discourse.WatchList.reopenClass({
  find: function() {
    return jQuery.getJSON("watch_lists").then(function(json) {
      return json.watch_lists.map(function(attrs) {
        return Discourse.WatchList.create(attrs);
      }
    });
  }
});
```